# Priority of nested function in Mathematica

Tags: recursion, functional-style, piecewise

I am facing a small problem with the nested function in Mathematica. Please take a look at the attached Code below.

```
T2 = 2/3;
VR = 0.6; 
VDD = 3; 
zb = 1+T2; 

Nest[(Piecewise[{1+T1+(T1/T2)*(1-#), 0 <= # < zb}, {# - T2 , zb < # <= VDD/VR}}]) &, Range [ 1,3,1], 1]
```

I got the output:

```
{1+T1,1-T1/2,1-2 T1}    0<={1,2,3}<5/3
5/3                     5/3<={1,2,3}<=5.
0                       True
```

I want the Piecewise function takes the highest priority before Nest function. This means depending on the value of parameter (`x` or `#`), the Piecewise function decides which "piecewise" will be used.

Piecewise function:

```
= 1+T1+(T1/T2)*(1-x) if 0 < x < zb
```

or

```
= 1-T2               if zb < x < VDD/VR
```

For example: `zb = 1+T2` (`zb` is the boundary condition) => with `T2 = 2/3` we have `zb = 5/3`. So if `x = 1`, The output of piecewise function will be `1+T1+(T1/T2)*(1-x)`. After that, the `Nest` function will be implemented continuously with `x = 1, 2, 3` and FINAL output will be a vector (with `T1` is the parameter).

Also, I would like to give another example with the expression inside the Nest function is `T1*x*(1-x)` and its output what i want with my Piecewise function

```
Nest[T1 #(1-#)&,Range[0.01,0.03,0.01],1]
```

And the output:

```
{0.0099 T1,0.0196 T1,0.0291 T1}
```

Really appreciate your supports.

BRs,

Ha

Comment: @NguyenHa maybe this then: `Nest[
 Map[Piecewise[
    {{1 + T1 + (T1/T2)*(1 - #), 0 <= # < zb},
     {# - T2, zb < # <= VDD/VR}}
    ] &],
 Range[1, 3, 1], 1]` but `T1` needs to be defined.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you so much for your comment. It works perfectly now. Really appreciate your help. BRs - Ha

Answer (score 3):

`Nest[f, arg, n]` applies `f` to `arg`

```
Nest[f, {a1, a2, a3}, 2] (* f[f[{a1, a2, a3}]] *)
```

but from your description it is clear that you want to map `f /@ arg`, so one step is missing.

Quick fix is to add `Map`, in operator form:

```
Nest[Map[f], {a1, a2, a3}, 2] (*{f[f[a1]], f[f[a2]], f[f[a3]]}*)
```

or classical:

```
Nest[Map[f, #] &, {a1, a2, a3}, 2] 
  (*don't forget & for your f if f is explicitly written with slots `#` e.g.:*)

Nest[Map[#^2 &(*!*), #] &(*!*), {a1, a2, a3}, 2]
```

sometimes `Map` is not needed because certain functions automatically thread over `Lists`, e.g. `Plus/Times/Power` etc. So the above example can be written:

```
Nest[#^2 &, {a1, a2, a3}, 2]
```

but `Piecewise` is not doing this so you need `Map`.

p.s. another way is to make your function listable:

```
Nest[Function[a, Panel[a], Listable], {a1, a2, a3}, 2]
```

The last one is just a teaser and not as general as initial examples. I'm encouraging you to do help lookup or search around to learn more.